# Exporting a random RSA PublicKey from Java and importing it in JavaScript using Web Crypto

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, rsa, webcrypto-api

I am able to transfer a byte array from a Java server to a JavaScript server (is received as an Int32Array). With this, I want to be able to transfer a PublicKey generated in Java and receive it as a CryptoKey in JavaScript.

The RSA Public key is generated in Java like so:

```
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
generator.initialize(2048, sr);
KeyPair kp = generator.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey pKey = kp.getPublic();
```

What I have tried is to use Key#getEncoded() to get the public key as a byte array, transfer it to JavaScript using the aformenetioned method, and then import it like so:

```
const subtle = window.crypto.subtle;
await subtle.importKey("spki", array, { name: "RSA-OAEP", hash: "SHA-256" }, false, [ "encrypt" ])
```

Where "array" is the Int32Array received from the Java server. This does not work however, and I always get a non-descript DOMException stating "Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements". I have done the obvious troubleshooting, checking that the array is the same before and after sending, turning the TypedArray into an ArrayBuffer, encoding and decoding in base64 as a byte sanity check, and trying different algorithms but to no avail.

Some resources:

Here is a sample key#getEncoded() byte array as reported by Java before sending (after sending is Int32Array([...]) with the same contents)

```
[48, -126, 1, 32, 48, 11, 6, 9, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 1, 1, 10, 3, -126, 1, 15, 0, 48, -126, 1, 10, 2, -126, 1, 1, 0, -44, -97, 125, 40, -104, -77, -56, 30, 64, -51, -44, 35, -91, 83, 43, -92, 1, 104, -7, -71, 61, -111, 74, -17, -43, 96, 47, 5, 71, 57, -23, -80, 12, 23, -89, -5, 18, 56, 32, -125, -48, 115, -126, 45, 71, 73, -53, -68, -104, -95, 18, -76, 21, 22, 122, 26, -89, -128, -118, 99, -65, 89, -81, -120, 72, -85, 20, 44, -119, -38, 4, -1, -69, -105, -70, -52, 126, 58, 86, -9, 4, -55, 104, -81, 21, -91, -128, -101, -82, -15, -1, -4, -13, -116, 48, -91, -60, 81, 111, 53, 126, 91, -46, 16, -5, -99, 73, -40, -99, -24, -46, -75, -99, 48, -67, 92, -92, -78, -115, 76, -35, -51, 75, -56, 70, 56, -10, 13, -108, 56, 79, 34, -22, -123, -91, -12, 9, -21, -32, 22, -88, -79, -13, -35, 61, 24, -115, -93, 40, 46, -88, 5, -105, -69, 82, -57, 10, -15, -91, 21, 53, -60, -31, -102, -63, -35, 71, -72, 50, 2, 37, 93, -70, -87, -110, -69, -10, 88, 51, 118, 30, 45, -11, 74, -92, -109, -10, 102, 79, -128, 14, 61, 94, -100, 69, 97, 56, 38, -14, 29, -85, -78, 2, 31, -127, -107, 86, -16, -114, -7, -83, 31, 77, -120, 77, 73, 114, 38, -124, 31, 116, -83, 39, -36, 85, 92, 86, 52, 22, -90, -47, 101, 16, 94, -16, -95, -33, 68, 112, 88, 94, -47, 121, -83, 3, -80, 111, 21, -42, 65, -101, 72, -126, 4, -83, -11, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1]
```

The same data expressed in hexadecimal

```
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
```

Thank you to anybody who takes time to help or reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all a working solution: The DER encoded X.509/SPKI key generated with `Key#getEncoded()` is Base64 encoded and then imported to the JavaScript side as follows:

```js
(async () => {
    const subtle = window.crypto.subtle;
    var keyAB = b642ab("MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuuKRgspvg47d4I3pAzCIWKSim2Rs1QeTVE1Hs+P099PkiuMt5dq5GIaIT1DZTYwJrwtUpxnMcr1TNdWGGfovDLJuIRXUFeST1xOD9+rA4FhVZPO/x6ts2TYKiueEq/qPlXREXw8aVq+msw0nYhHFIAAyrtmj7UR6gD3xxl1ghviIycKqUf7rL98b1d6YkYoNW62aIP/u3cJ5v3Fhnth02Cb02M/fX5gvFKJ3Nj2ARbLygZWbO3U09Vs/hnElxE2k1sKxYRqImJdQM04oQOXVVpafZP7eF9/T+YYDxMLcEKAwH9z0fTt9HaL4gyiDWUT02r6qWF7vI85I1jrPLn71mQIDAQAB")

    var key = await subtle.importKey("spki", new Uint8Array(keyAB), { name: "RSA-OAEP", hash: "SHA-256" }, false, [ "encrypt" ])   
    console.log(key)
})();

function b642ab(base64string){
    return Uint8Array.from(atob(base64string), c => c.charCodeAt(0)).buffer;
}
```

The problem is caused by the `Int32Array` type you used. A typed array is an array-like view of an underlying `ArrayBuffer`. In an `Int32Array` each element corresponds to 4 bytes.
Since your `Int32Array` contains the *same* values as your `Key#getEncoded()`, the underlying `ArrayBuffer` contains 4 times as many values and therefore no longer corresponds to the original key.

Comment: Hmm, not quite. This method works for the sample Base64 string you provided, but try it on one received from my Java server (posted to https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/raw/pijowoxuza), it does not work. Exact same "Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements" error, no stack trace. Greatly appreciate the help though!

Comment: @WasabiThumbs - The code posted in the question generates a public key in X.509/SPKI format. However, the key posted in the link of the comment is a public key in PKCS#1 format and therefore actually cannot have been generated with the Java code! Is there any relevant information missing from your question? Note that WebCrypto does not support the PKCS#1 format. So you have to generate the key *directly* in X.509/SPKI format (e.g. with the posted Java code) or convert the PKCS#1 key to a format supported by WebCrypto.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I changed the code since my original post trying to get it to work. Reverted it, then it worked fine. My bad! Your expertise and help is greatly appreciated.